# Grabbing only total number from `loc` (lines of code) command

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

So, I have a GitHub repository that I want to display the lines of code of the project on. So, I found a tool called `loc` (lines of code) [here](https://github.com/cgag/loc). In the tool, it outputs the lines of code like so:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language             Files        Lines        Blank      Comment         Code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C++                      1          567           29           22          516
C/C++ Header             2          245           12           15          218
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                    3          812           41           37          734
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any way that I could `grep` only the Total row in the Code column? The options for the `loc` command only consist of this:

```
USAGE:
    loc [FLAGS] [OPTIONS] [target]...

FLAGS:
        --files      Show stats for individual files
    -h, --help       Prints help information
    -V, --version    Prints version information

OPTIONS:
        --exclude <REGEX>    Rust regex of files to exclude
        --include <REGEX>    Rust regex matching files to include. Anything not matched will be excluded
        --sort <COLUMN>      Column to sort by

ARGS:
    <target>...    File or directory to count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `grep`, but you need two steps:

1. Filter the line that contains `Total`:

   ```
   grep 'Total'
   ```
2. Display only the last number (consecutive digits) from that line:

   ```
   grep -Po '\d+$'
   ```

   `-P` switches to PCRE regex mode, which is needed for it to understand that `\d` means "any digit (0-9)".
   `-o` tells it to only display the matched sequence, not the whole line.
   `$` matches the end of the line.

Together these snippets make up the command below:

```
loc | grep 'Total' | grep -Po '\d+$'
```

---

If we assume you have a plain text file containing a line like this:

> Current lines of code in this project: 123

You can edit this file and replace the number in this line with the value stored in the Bash variable `$linecount` using the `sed` command below. Of course you must store the total line count in that variable first, like this:

```
linecount=$(loc | grep 'Total' | grep -Po '\d+$')

sed -i -E "s/(Current lines of code in this project: )[[:digit:]]+/\1$linecount/" README.MD
```